# ЧПУ на сайте при использовании цифровой индексации

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, чпу

Делаю сайт с ЧПУ при помощи mod_rewrite. Содержание страницы зависит от города. Город определен по ID. В итоге реальная ссылка имеет вид `mysite.ru/CityPage.php?City_ID=...`  Привести нужно к виду `mysite.ru/Moscow`, например. Но `City_ID` - это не текстовая переменная.

Как сделать переименование страниц, используя числовой ID? (непонятна сама логика, как обычно поступают в такой ситуации)

Comment: Ну так добавьте в таблицу городов поле с кодами и ищите город не по ИД, а по коду.

Comment: Почему-то хотелось именно по ID искать. Решил, что так быстрее будет.

Comment: Как вариант можете использовать после определения ID города php-переадресацию... как то так? $city='Moscow'; switch($City_ID){ case 15: $city='Novosibirsk'; break; } header("Location: /$city");

Comment: Добавьте в таблицу индекс по полю `код` и будет то же самое.